# Validation with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code at here:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mBBPh/3/)

But the jsfiddle said it has error :

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xa2ea90c>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0xa2ef70c>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xa2ea90c>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0xa2ef12c>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

I have tried at my main program and this JS doesn't work, so I try at jsfiddle then I got that result. What happened with my JS? because I have same JS (different name of form and textbox) but it works perfectly..

Comment: Paste JS Fiddle links as a hyperlink, do not highlight them, as it is not a code

Comment: Do try to check the JSON that you have there to make sure it validates. Something like [JSON Parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) might be instructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

multiple problems

1. script was onload
2. validate method name and an element had the same id `alasan`
3. textarea had a default value  (one space)

Fixed [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aU7bJ/):

```
function validate(myform)
{
    if(document.myform.alasan.value == "")
    {

        alert("Alasan harus diisi");
        document.myform.alasan.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about console.log, but thanks, it works now! I'll google it later about that console log. Once again, thanks!